# Confusing "Add Comment" text on deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't recall seeing this in the past, so I'm not sure if this is something new.

On deleted answers, the "Add Comment" link is disabled. That makes sense. But there is also a note saying that comments require 50 reputation with a link to [the privileges page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

It seems like either the reputation requirement text or the whole "add comment" section should be removed for these answers.

[image: add comment section]

Comment: Moderators can now add comments to deleted answers, so it is probably related to that change. I believe (but am not sure) that the OP can also make comments on content of theirs that is deleted (I know they can see the comments, I'm just not sure if they can add new ones).

Comment: That would make sense for it appearing recently. It confused me when I saw it - making me wonder if I had accidentally been logged out. Why else would it be telling me I needed 50 rep points?

Comment: On deleted answers, I'm seeing `comments disabled on deleted / locked posts`, but I can vote to un-delete answers - from the screenshot it looks like you don't have that yet.  Maybe that's also partially related somehow?

Comment: @izkata 20k rep gives "Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges". I'm not there yet. In that case, the note about 50 rep to leave comments is the wrong message to be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.  This bug has already been handled here: ["Requires 50 reputation" to comment on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190180/requires-50-reputation-to-comment-on-deleted-posts).  For deleted and locked answers, most users (i.e., everyone but mods) should see "comments disabled for locked / deleted posts" (or something very close to that).  OPs cannot comment on deleted and locked posts, either.  Only mods.